# Best way to insert large xml files into xml columns (on remote SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, insert, stream

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_XML]
(
   [XmlFileID]       [BIGINT] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [FileName]        [NVARCHAR](500) NULL,   
   [XmlData]         [XML] NULL,
   [DateCreated]     [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
)
```

The method I am currently using to fill the table is this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_XML] 
                                    ( [XmlData] , 
                                    [FileName] , 
                                    [DateCreated]
                                    ) 
                        VALUES (@XMLData, @FileName, GETDATE())";

    using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new FileStream(item.XmlFileName, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500).Value = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.XmlFileName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter("@XMLData", SqlDbType.Xml)
        {
            Value = new SqlXml(xmlReader)
        });

        SetConnectionParameters(cmd);

        cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

But this will not work with very large XMLs because the whole file is loaded in memory and I get OutOfMemory exceptions.

What is the best approach to insert a large (>100MB) XML file into the XMLData column from a .net application running on a different machine than the server?

Bulk insert is out of the question since the SQL server will not have access to my XML file.

Comment: I've never used it myself, but what about the [SQLXML Bulk Load utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171993(v=sql.105).aspx)? It's a COM object so you still have to write a program to use it, but it doesn't require SQL Server to have direct access to the XML file.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: I think you should try to use xml in chunks if possible and also look at this link if it helps you
http://sortedbits.com/reading-big-xml-file-with-c-xmlreader/

Comment: @BogdanB: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to load XML into a database is to NOT load XML into a database. If you REALLY have a need to do that (and you probably dont) you should be looking at a noSQL solution like Cassandra or Mongo.

If "need" to store XML, chances are you have made a wrong architectural choice elsewhere. Consider if there are better ways to represent the information. XML is an interchange format, not a good format for keeping information around long term.

All that being said, you could use BCP or the OLEDB interface which supports streaming. Here is an example:
[Examples of Bulk Import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx)

Comment: Or RavenDB! Using @ThomasKejser recommendation, the XML becomes very easy to search and index. I've stored XML in Oracle before and you end up writing 2 sets of data access layers - one for the DB and one for the XML parsing. Not fun :(

Comment: I tend to agree with @thomas that storing large XML files on remote SQL Servers is fundamentally wrong. This need to be rearchitectured.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Just change your whole storage format, that'll be easier. LOL

Comment: @Porco It WILL likely be easier to change the whole storage format. If you have designed a storage format that "needs" XML to be stored - you are on the path to madness. The point here is that it looks like the OP is trying to solve the wrong problem - instead of restating the problem in terms that will lead to a good design. Note that if you insist on storing XML, I provided the info in the last paragraph (and I added a little link now too)

Answer (score 1):

Below is one potential way to chunk this using only .NET. I have not tried executing this, but it should work.

```
    public static ChunkedXmlInsert(XmlItem item)
    {
        int bufferSize = 65536;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            CreateTempTable(connection);

            int position = 0;
            using (StreamReader textStream = File.OpenText(item.XmlFileName))
            {
                char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
                int length = textStream.Read(buffer, position, buffer.Length);
                long id = InsertFirstBlock(connection, new string(buffer, 0, length));

                while (textStream.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    position += length;
                    length = textStream.Read(buffer, position, buffer.Length);
                    AppendBlock(connection, id, new string(buffer, 0, length));
                }
            }

            CopyRecordFromTemp(connection, id);
        }
    }

    private static void CreateTempTable(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE #TBL_XML (
                                                              [XmlFileID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                                                              [FileName] [NVARCHAR](500) NULL,
                                                              [XmlData] [NVARCHAR(MAX)] NULL,
                                                              [DateCreated] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
                                                          )";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    private static long InsertFirstBlock(SqlConnection connection, string text)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO #TBL_XML
                                                        ( [XmlData] , 
                                                          [FileName] , 
                                                          [DateCreated]
                                                        ) 
                                        VALUES (@XMLData, @FileName, GETDATE()); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.XmlFileName));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlData", text);
            return (long)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    private static void AppendBlock(SqlConnection connection, long id, string text)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"UPDATE #TBL_XML
                                            SET XmlData = XmlData + @xmlData
                                    WHERE XmlFileID = @XmlFileID";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlData", text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlFileID", id);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    private static long CopyRecordFromTemp(SqlConnection connection, long id)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_XML] ([XmlData], [FileName], [DateCreated])
                                    SELECT CONVERT(xml, [XmlData]), [FileName], [DateCreated]
                                    FROM #TBL_XML
                                    WHERE XmlFileID = @XmlFileID; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
            return (long)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This article provides some background information for working with LOB's.
[Check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t%28VS.80%29.aspx)

I just tested the OPENROWSET BULK syntax with an xml field, and it works.  If your SQL server has access to the file, that is one option (and I just noticed it is not an option, so I will experiment more).  Otherwise, you would need to try an offset write solution.  So far, I can't get that .WRITE method to work with an xml field.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184%28SQL.105%29.aspx) indicates you can use BCP to insert XML.
 That would require the SQL Server client tools to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to store data at remote SQL Server you need to transfer whole file content through a network. In general there is two ways:

- you transfer data to remote server;
- remote server reads data from your local file.

The second way is not in the scope of this question. And the first could be done in several ways supposing you implement stored procedure at the remote server:

- implementing 'upload' functionality which transfers data in portions, joins them at server's side and stores in DB;
- packing XML content at client side and unpacking and storing at server side;
- combination of above methods.

Answer (score 0):

`@xmlstring` is input xml

```
INSERT INTO @Temptbl           
   SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), e.query('./Name/text()')) LogNumber             
   FROM @xmlstring.nodes('//RootNode/Root') AS n(e)     

select Temptbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the stored procedure to insert the large xml file into the database.
In that stored procedure you can send your xml file input as nvarchar(max). Note that the nvarchar(max) will accept up to 8000 characters.

In your code the main flow is that you are passing xml from file stream which is very costly affair.

If your file is to large from nvarchar(max) then you can use more input parameters in your stored procedure and then concatenate these input parameters to insert the single value as a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like SqlXml parameter type accepts XmlReader as an input.

As a stream-based reader this should remove the memory limitation you are experiencing.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    SqlParameter sqlParameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
    sqlParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    sqlParameter.Value = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml(xmlReader);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Notice he is already doing exactly what you have typed already.  new SqlParameter("@XMLData", SqlDbType.Xml)
        {
            Value = new SqlXml(xmlReader)
        });

Comment: Indeeed you right. My assumption was 'sqlParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input' would stream xml data into SQL Server. But after looking inside the implementation surprisingly it simply reads everything into memory even when expects a stream as an input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a SSIS package to import your XML files into a SQL Server database.
Then, if you need to use C#, you can execute this package programmatically.
It will be more efficient and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Store the XML-files in a FileTable.

Answer (score -1):

> 1) Create a stored procedure to insert in table. 
>  
>   2) Pass your xml as varchar(max) from C# code.

OR

> 2) Break your file in chunks.
>  
>   3) Execute the SP with XML as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Please use sql xml bulk loader
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171806.aspx